# developing an external arrow keys using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, ipad, html5-canvas

I'm trying to develop a game using html5, css and a little bit of jquery.

Sometimes I have achieved to make the game work via Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. My issue is that during my experiment, on the iPad2 the game works except that the object is not moving, so I was looking for a solution to develop somehow an external key arrows without using many scripts, the object suppose to do only jump, left and right. I have looked for many solution to this I couldn't find a good rendered movement. I have even tried to create an JavaScript that handle the movements smoothly.

I'm looking for a way to handle the movement via mobile using node.js or any available source that could help me achieving the smooth jump.

I have looked for many resources and i want to make the controls as simple to users to interact with.

Both Chrome and Firefox works well with no problem, except Safari specifically the one in iPad 2 or 3...

Here is some of the controls , where is my mistake in this

```
var left, right;
    left = mie ? 1:0;
    right = 2;

    document.body.addEventListener('mousedown' , function (e) {
    console.log(e.button);
    if(key === left){
        dir = "left";
        player.isMovingLeft = true;
    } else if (key === right){
        dir = "right";
        player.isMovingRight = true;
    }

    if(key == 32) {
        if(firstRun === true)
            init();
        else
            reset();
    }
    };

    var left, right;
    left = mie ? 1:0;
    right = 2;

    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup' , function (e) {
        console.log(e.button);
        if(key === left){
            dir = "left";
            player.isMovingLeft = false;
        } else if (key === right) {
            dir = "right";
            player.isMovingRight = false;
        }
    };

//Accelerations produces when the user hold the keys
if (player.isMovingLeft === true) {
    player.x += player.vx;
    player.vx -= 0.15;
} else {
    player.x += player.vx;
    if (player.vx < 0) player.vx += 0.1;
}

if (player.isMovingRight === true) {
    player.x += player.vx;
    player.vx += 0.15;
} else {
    player.x += player.vx;
    if (player.vx > 0) player.vx -= 0.1;
}

// Speed limits!
if(player.vx > 8)
    player.vx = 8;
else if(player.vx < -8)
    player.vx = -8;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be an obvious answer, but have you added touch events (not just mouse events)?

If not, that'll be the problem.

Check out [Apples documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1) for examples.
The gist of it is this:

> element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
>   element.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
>   element.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
>   element.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchCancel, false);

I recommend you a use a library such as [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/). It makes adding events & gestures super easy.

Comment: I have applied the mouse events !! the addEventListener i have tried it out, will have a look again at this documentation thanks jarrod.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this as a solution to support both touch and mouse:
[hand.js](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx)

From the article:

> How about being able to write a single code base for handling mouse,
>   pen, touch in your web site that will work across all modern browsers?
>   Here is a polyfill that will help you use Pointer Events and offer
>   users a great experience on your site independently of the modern
>   browser they are using.

<kbd>**[DOWNLOAD HAND.JS FROM CODEPLEX](http://handjs.codeplex.com/releases/view/109200)**</kbd>

Comment: i have tried out the code , for some reason it crashes , thanks